# Specify "base" from-table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have 3 tables: A, B, C.

```
A: id, fieldA
B: id, id_a, fieldB; id_a - foreign key for A.id
C: id, id_b, fieldC; id_b - foreign key for B.id
```

Now I want to run this sql query:

```
SELECT A.fieldA,
       B.fieldB
FROM   C
       LEFT JOIN B
            LEFT JOIN A
              ON A.id = B.id_a
         ON B.id = C.id_b
WHERE  C.fieldC = :myvalue
```

The SQLAlchemy query would be:

```
session.query(A.fieldA, B.fieldB).join(...).join(...).filter(C.fieldC == myvalue)
                                 ^------------------^ issue here
```

The problem is that all the joins will be applied to the table that was selected in the query first, i.e. in this case to A.

I can use some dummy hack like:

```
session.query(C.fieldC, A.fieldA, B.fieldB).join(B).join(A).filter(C.fieldC == myvalue)
              ^------^ I don't need this column
```

But, of course, this is not desirable.

Is there a way to specify base table that will have all the joins attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, you need:

- to specify the left part of the join using [`select_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from)
- and use an [`outerjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.outerjoin) (and *not* an inner join)

I don't have SQLAlchemy at hand right now, so I cannot guarantee this will work "out of the box", but something *like* that would be a good starting point:

```
session.query(A.fieldA, B.fieldB)        \
          .select_from(C)                \
          .outerjoin(B, ....)            \
          .outerjoin(A, ....)            \
          .filter(C.fieldC == myvalue)
```

Comment: Sheesh... Now I feel dumb, having missed that `select_from` in documentation. Thank you!